# Why is the Lint Reports folder not being generated in Gradle 7.0.2 when using 'gradlew lint' in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Lint Reports folder not generated in https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/663cE.png)

Not getting lint report after trying .gradlew lint.

I want to export xml / html report of Android Lint

Do I need to configure Android Studio in a certain way to see the reports folder?

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000, built on August 27, 2021

gradle.properties fille contains this line

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8